# How to download a file from Draytek Vigor2132Fvn router over tftp?

Tags: tftp, draytek

I have a router which comes from some unknown ISP and after resetting it to default settings it's impossible to log in due to wrong password. Default admin/admin doesn't work and I already tried pretty much all combinations that Draytek routers use.

Previously I was able to log in because the seller somehow uploaded what he called `config file` to the device that made possible to login using admin/admin. But now after resetting, that doesn't work.

I tried contacting the seller with no luck - hence the question.

I've read that there's a way to connect over tftp and upload a file that contains changed credentials (just my assumption) - but how to do it ? I don't even know path/file...

I know that tftp mode works OK because I can upgrade the firmware (over tftp and it works flawlessly).

I haven't tried to connect over tftp from linux or mac computer. But - it would be very helpful If I knew internal file structure so I could figure out which file holds the login credentials...